# What kind of baritone is this voice & is it learned or naturally acquired?

Tags: voice, opera

I understand that there are different types of baritones. I am aware of a few such as the Dramatic Baritone, Dramatic Bass Baritone, Lyric Low Baritone, Verdi Baritone.

One of my favourite pop operatic baritones is Carlos Marin, best known for being the baritone of Il Divo. He has this wonderfully rich voice that I can't quite describe, but it sounds very 'full' and 'rich', if that makes sense hopefully.

Here are some of my favourite clips of him.

[Tonight @ 1:09 - 1:27](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AAyRjTJ3Ncw)

[Adagio @ 3:20 - 3:34](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2v3s7HWOis)

[Without You @ 2:45 - 3:24](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0Mgak3eGg0)

What kind of baritone would he be categorised under? Do all baritones have this 'rich' tone to their voice? Is this something that comes naturally, or is it learned? I myself am a baritone and I can sometimes acquire that same (or similar) style of 'fullness' in the voice, but it does take a fair bit of effort. Is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most vocal coloring is natural. It can be developed but mainly it is what you're born with. That is why you can recognize who is singing, by their voice. As singers age their voice changes, usually getting darker. What you have here is best known as a dramatic baritone.